# Trying to create an object with Json data

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I am studying Swift and creating a little app for college. I am using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON to work with my API.

Model Products

```
class Products {
    var id: Int {
        get {
            return self.id
        }
        set {
            self.id = newValue
        }
    }

    var name: String {
        get {
            return self.name
        }
        set {
            self.name = newValue
        }
    }

    var description: String {
        get {
            return self.description
        }
        set {
            self.description = newValue
        }
    }

    var price: String {
        get {
            return self.price
        }
        set {
            self.price = newValue
        }
    }

    init(id: Int, name: String, description: String, price: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.price = price
    }
}
```

My ViewController

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Alamofire.request(.GET, Urls.menu).responseJSON { request in
            if let json = request.result.value {
                let data = JSON(json)

                for (_, subJson): (String, JSON) in data {
                    let product = Products(id: subJson["id"].int!, name: subJson["name"].string!, description: subJson["description"].string!, price: subJson["price"].string!)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run my code, I receive an error in my Model Products, line 14:

> Thread 1: EX_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff5e961ff8)

In the setter of my property id.

I check my error log in xcode, and it shows that this setter is called more than 250 thousand times.

Can anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code causes an infinite loop because the explicit setter calls itself again and again.

In Swift properties are synthesized implicitly, just declaring them is sufficient.

```
class Products {
    var id: Int 
    var name: String
    var description: String 
    var price: String 

    init(id: Int, name: String, description: String, price: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.price = price
    }
}
```